# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` in node.js server to kafka connect connection

Tags: java, node.js, apache-kafka-connect

I use curl to submit to our Kafka Connect service a JSON request message with information about the connector, it is working successfully.

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ \"name\": \"inventory-connector\", \"config\": { \"connector.class\": \"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector\", \"tasks.max\": \"1\", \"database.hostname\": \"mysql\", \"database.port\": \"3306\", \"database.user\": \"debezium\", \"database.password\": \"dbz\", \"database.server.id\": \"184054\", \"database.server.name\": \"dbserver1\", \"database.whitelist\": \"inventory\", \"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"kafka:9092\", \"database.history.kafka.topic\": \"dbhistory.inventory\" } }'
```

now I am using node.js server to send data to kafka connect server.

```
  var body = {
  "name": "abc",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "inventory",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
  }
};

  var options = {
      method: 'PUT',
      uri: 'http://localhost/connectors/abc/config',
      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
      },
      json: true ,
      body: body
  };

  rp(options)
      .then(function (data) {
          return res.status(200).json({ 'data': data});
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: err});
      });
```

however the code throw out an error: saying

```
{ StatusCodeError: 500 - {"error_code":500,"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 42] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"config\"])"}
```

The API description is from https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html

[image]

Comment: Perhaps set `json: false` for the request-promise call and pass the body stringified: `body: JSON.stringify(body)`?  Seems like Java is seeing an Object when it is expecting a string.

Comment: why are you using PUT not POST? also can you share the code of uri: 'http://localhost/connectors/abc/config endpoint

Comment: POST and PUT doesn't matter, the API has both POST and PUT endpoints

Comment: It does matter. The PUT doesn't have a `name` or `config` field in the body

Comment: POST (create) requires a "name" property and a "config" property.  PUT (update or create if not present) requires the name in the URI while the body is an anonymous config object.

Answer (score 10):

If I read the confluent doc correctly, you did mix up two different API endpoints.

In your code, you use the endpoint `/connectors/abc/config`, which according to the documentation takes a single config object as toplevel, so like this:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "database.hostname": "mysql",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "debezium",
  "database.password": "dbz",
  "database.server.id": "184054",
  "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
  "database.whitelist": "inventory",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
}
```

But your JSON object looks like it was meant for the `/connectors` endpoint.

Changing either the endpoint or your JSON object to match the endpoint you have chosen may fix the problem.

Comment: Spot on. That was it for me. Also, for those who are using `curl` version >= `7.82.0` you can simply use `curl <kakfa_broker> --json @your_connector_config.json`. No need to add all that headers for POST and `content-type`.